# openvino where is deployment_tools folder?

Tags: python, openvino

everyone

Recently I need to convert an onnx model into intermediate representation, so I git clone the openvino. But I didn't see deployment_tools folder in the project. Even I install it by following the installation guide.

Also another problem, it seem that openvino support python. I run the cmake by these command, that should make the python3.6 support the openvino calling I guess (import openvino?)

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .. \
-DENABLE_PYTHON=ON -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=`which python3.6` \
-DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so \
-DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.6 -DNGRAPH_ONNX_IMPORT_ENABLE=ON
```

After it successfully cmake and make jobs... I try to import openvino, and it does not work. So I want to ask how I can use it in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model Optimizer in master branch of [openvino](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino) GitHub repository has been moved and merged into [openvino/tools/mo](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino/tree/master/tools/mo) directory.

Run [setupvars](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino/tree/master/scripts/setupvars) script in terminal to update OpenVINO™ environment variables before importing openvino in Python.